# create table from selected value to be new column in new table

Tags: sql, database

I have SQL (phpmyadmin) syntax like that and its return some value.

> SELECT data FROM table_data WHERE data = 'input';
>
> > Value of
> >
> > data in table_data
> >     ========== 
> >     data1 
> >     data2 
> >     data3 
> >     data4

My Question is, how can I make a new table_column in db from selected value to be new column in my new table?

> CREATE TABLE table_data_new AS SELECT data FROM table_data WHERE data = 'input';

if I use that syntax, that make new table but the column in selected value is copied to my new table. Anybody, please help me solve that problem :)

> > I want schema like this :
> >
> > table_new_data
> >     
> >     have column like this 
> >     ============== 
> >     
> >     data1 | data2 | data3 | data4

Comment: Which server you are using? MSSQL, MySQL .....???

Comment: Do you mean you want a new table, without any data in it?

Comment: Really what you looking for? Please explain with expected output table

Comment: I use local phpmyadmin

Comment: I guess one option is to build a dynamic sql and execute it... but as pointed out above, need more info.

Comment: If u just want an empty table add where 1=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you need  a create like  (create an empty table based on an existing table )

fro sql server you can use

```
 SELECT * INTO table_data_new  FROM table_data  WHERE 1 = 0;
```

for oracle  and mysql (phpmyadmin)

```
CREATE TABLE table_data_new  LIKE table_data  ;
```

in phpmyadmin you have a proper panel for create like  tables (panel operation)